# Android MediaPlayer Error Cannot Play this video

Tags: android, video, android-mediarecorder

I am working on custom camera app for video recording. Recorded video gets stored on sdcard. 
The code works fine for all the devices except for T-Mobile S3 (SGH-T999 android v 4.1.2) where I get 'Cannot play this video' error. I have researched alot for this issue, tried with changing parameters also but still not able to solve.

```
W/VideoView( 4490): Unable to open content: /storage/sdcard0/MyCameraApp/VID_20140807_130327.ogg

    W/VideoView( 4490): java.io.IOException: setDataSourceFD failed.: status=0x80000000

    W/VideoView( 4490):  at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(Native Method)

    W/VideoView( 4490):  at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1204)

    W/VideoView( 4490):  at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1175)

    W/VideoView( 4490):  at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1121)

    W/VideoView( 4490):  at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:953)

    W/VideoView( 4490):  at android.widget.VideoView.openVideo(VideoView.java:249)

    W/VideoView( 4490):  at android.widget.VideoView.access$2000(VideoView.java:51)

    W/VideoView( 4490):  at android.widget.VideoView$6.surfaceCreated(VideoView.java:492)

    W/VideoView( 4490):  at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:609)

    W/VideoView( 4490):  at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:86)

    W/VideoView( 4490):  at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:178)

    W/VideoView( 4490):  at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:707)

    W/VideoView( 4490):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1955)

    W/VideoView( 4490):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1119)

    W/VideoView( 4490):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4553)

    W/VideoView( 4490):  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)

    W/VideoView( 4490):  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)

    W/VideoView( 4490):  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)

    W/VideoView( 4490):  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)

    W/VideoView( 4490):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)

    W/VideoView( 4490):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)

    W/VideoView( 4490):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

    W/VideoView( 4490):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)

    W/VideoView( 4490):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

    W/VideoView( 4490):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

    W/VideoView( 4490):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)

    W/VideoView( 4490):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)

    W/VideoView( 4490):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

    D/VideoView( 4490): Error: 1,0

    V/MediaPlayerService(  187): Client(13) destructor pid = 4490

    I/AudioSink(  187): +++ close

    I/AudioSink(  187): --- close

    V/AudioSink(  187): closeSession

    V/MediaPlayerService(  187): disconnect(13) from pid 4490
```

Code snippet.

```
CamcorderProfile camcorderProfile=CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
    camcorderProfile.videoFrameWidth = width;
    camcorderProfile.videoFrameHeight = ht;
    camcorderProfile.videoCodec = MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264;
    camcorderProfile.audioCodec = MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB;
    camcorderProfile.fileFormat = MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4;
    mMediaRecorder.setProfile(camcorderProfile);
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(width, ht);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: May be a device specific issue. Just check with other play store apps with video recording in  your issue produced device. If you are getting the same problem most probably a device specific issue.  I got an issue when i implemented the custom camera in Samsung galaxy 10 inch. Except galaxy 10 inch tab video recording is perfectly working. If i record video and rotating the device the application got stuck. Sometimes it saving and getting the cannot play error. Then i downloaded some video capturing apps from play store to that particular device  and i got the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please watch the specification of your testing device. You may use raw and mp4 as the common option

Comment: Event if I use MP4 format for saving video, it gives following exception,

V/AwesomePlayer(  187): setDataSource_l: Extractor failed in header parsing or corrupted media file
V/MediaPlayerService(  187):  setDataSource
E/MediaPlayerService(  187):   error: -2147483648
:
:
W/VideoView( 4490): Unable to open content: /storage/sdcard0/MyCameraApp/VID_20140807_130327.mp4
W/VideoView( 4490): java.io.IOException: setDataSourceFD failed.: status=0x80000000
:
:
D/VideoView( 4490): Error: 1,0